# Empty Array Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I populate with data from an array. It displays available networks, and populates the table view based upon its findings. I try and recall `reloadData` to the table view in one of my methods, but for some odd reason the app crashed with the error:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

To recreate the issue, I first scan for the networks. There are 2 available and they're just chilling. I connect to one, then I go to disconnect. I click disconnect, fire a `reloadData` to refresh the table view, then that is when the app crashes with the error. If I delete the `reloadData` call, it doesn't crash and goes along fine. This ties in with another question that I have about refreshing the table view to not display the network unless it's connected to it, I thought `reloadData` would work but it hates me. I'm at a loss of what to do to fix this bug and refresh properly.

Comment: How are you declaring the array?

Comment: @savner I'm declaring it locally in the method I used to populate the table view.

Comment: This looks like that reload is not called, Log the call of reload

Comment: If the is array local to some method, how are you getting the size of the array for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? (This is a hint.)

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint for all objective-c exceptions, so you can see where the exception actually happens. Instructions here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: @JoshCaswell I get it by using a precompiled call from a separate file. @AlexWien I set an nslog before and after it, and it appears to have fired. I'm unsure of how to NSlog it more specifically. The strange thing is that `reloadData` fires fine in other methods.

Comment: The table view's data source needs to use the same set of data for all of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Otherwise you end up with errors like this one.